# find the domain and represent geometrically $f(x,y)=\sqrt{\frac{4x-x^2-y^2}{2x-2x^2-y^2}}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

help me with this excercises..
find the domain and represent geometrically

## $$f(x,y)=\sqrt{\frac{4x-x^2-y^2}{2x-x^2-y^2}}$$

i´ve tried.
$$D_{x,y}=[(x,y)∈R^2 : f(x,y)∈R]$$ then
$\frac{4x-x^2-y^2}{2x-x^2-y^2}≥0  $     y   $2x-x^2-y^2>0$
....

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1) Setting $4x-x^2-y^2=0$ and completing the square gives $(x-2)^2+y^2=4$,

$\;\;\;$so the numerator is positive at all points inside this circle.

2) Setting $2x-x^2-y^2=0$ and completing the square gives $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$,

$\;\;\;$so the denominator is positive at all points inside this circle.

Now use that the function is defined at all points where the numerator and denominator have the same sign, or where the numerator is 0 and the denominator is nonzero.

Comment: thanks, i understand, although this expression i writed bad ehhe,